# Subject for 感じ in the following sentence

Tags: translation

I have a question about the 感じ in 「私の食生活が気になっている感じですか」? Who is the owner of those feelings? Is it something like 'It feels that you are interested in my eating habits' or maybe 'Are you feeling that you are interested in my eating habits' ?

> 人A「う、うん。敬礼はいいから。なんか・・・・・・大丈夫？変なもんでも食べた？」
>
> 人B「食べました！ラボの食事はおいしくなかったです！もう～、だめだめ！」
>
> 人A「や、そうじゃなくて。それ以外に」
>
> 人B「にひひ、なになに～？私の食生活が気になっている**感じ**ですか～？も～、照れちゃうな～、うふふっ」
>
> 人A「うわ・・・・・・ほんとなんだこのノリ。酔っ払いかよ・・・・・・。」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that 感じ is always used in the sense of trying to point to *someone's* feelings/sentiments. If 感じ points to anyone's feelings, I'd say it would be the feelings of 人A.

In this usage, I think one can safely translate it with "like", as in

> 私の食生活が気になっている**感じ**ですか
>   So it's **like** you're interested in my eating habits?
>   So you're saying you're interested in my eating habits?

"like" is, similarly, trying to wonder what it "feels like" to someone else.

Comment: Maybe this is the same as what you're saying but I would go "huh, it seems like you've gotten interested in my eating habits?"

Comment: @virmaior Yeah, I usually try to leave recognizable traces of the original sentence in the translation (which of course practically always implies "badly translated"). I'd say that the second sentence is pretty close to your (native English speaker's) version.

Comment: The second one is great. I am little wary on the preciseness of using "like" for 感じ in this context... Since 感じ refers more to the texture of the entire line of questioning than to a similarity between what they are doing and this per se.

Comment: Since this answer does not mention it, I feel the urge to say that this usage of 「感じ」 is pretty "new" and really frivolous.  I just do not want the learners to think it is a normal usage and imitate it.  人A's last line responding to it reflects what I just said, too.