# How to interpret 感じの情報 in this sentence

Tags: interpretation

This is from a blog about Death Note

> L及び警察側の状況整理という感じの情報が出されていきます。

From episode 2, the context is a reunion were the police and  L are reviewing information about the kira case and one officer is reading tip offs.

I'm trying to interpret this and I have something like:

> there's the information of [a sense of the police and L making plans] that is going to be taken out (exposed in the reunion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

感じ literally means "feeling" of "sense", but this ～という感じの is just an informal way to avoid assertive tone, so it's like "kinda looks (to me) like ～", "along the lines of ～", "that might be called a ～", etc. In this case, it implies 状況整理 is the reviewer's own wording, i.e., no one in the anime actually said 状況整理.

- 状況整理: organization/summarizing/review of the current situation (of Kira's case)
- L及び警察側の状況整理: review of the situation seen from the L and police's side
- L及び警察側の状況整理という感じの情報: information that kind of looks like a review of the current situation seen from the L and police's side

See also:

- [Subject for 感じ in the following sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21106/5010)
- [Can someone please help me understand the structure of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33626/5010)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start piece by piece:

L及び警察側 = L and the police

状況整理 = assessing the situation

L及び警察側の状況整理 = L and police assessing the situation

L及び警察側の状況整理という感じ = The feeling of `"L and the police assessing the situation"`

L及び警察側の状況整理という感じの情報 = The information of the feeling of `"L and the police assessing the situation"`

L及び警察側の状況整理という感じの情報が出されていきます。 = The information of the feeling of `"L and the police assessing the situation"` is shown

To put it into more natural English, the show portrays the feeling that L and the police are assessing the situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary 感じ can be translates as "sensation", "feeling", "impression".
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/感じ/#je-14554](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%84%9F%E3%81%98/#je-14554)

So the translation becomes:
状況整理という感じの情報
An information that indicates like they are assessing the situation.